# Using an if statement, echo inside of an if statement echo?

Tags: php, mysql

I want it to, if user is not logged in, display PLEASE LOGIN, and if user is logged in display content

all of it works great, but the banned column is 0 = not banned and 1 = banned
but i want it to say if banned == 0 then say no and if banned == 1 then say yes
but when i do that it gives me an error

```
<?
if (!$UserLoggedIn) {
    
    echo "
    PLEASE LOGIN
    ";
} else {
    echo "
    <div style='
    background: #FFF;
    padding: 25px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px #bbb;
    margin: auto;
    position:relative;
    width: 600px;
    '>
    <center>
    Welcome, $GetLoggedUser->username 
      <br>
    Here's some statistics about your account:
      <br>
    Username: $GetLoggedUser->username
      <br>
    Email: $GetLoggedUser->email
      <br>
    UserID: $GetLoggedUser->id
      <br>
    Banned from game: 
    if($GetLoggedUser->banned == '0') { echo ' no '; } else { echo ' yes  '; }
      <br>
    Banned from website: $GetLoggedUser->Ban (obviously not or this page   wouldn't show up)
    <center/>
    <div/>
    ";
}
?>
```

Comment: Do not rely on [short open tags](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) working anywhere. They're old, deprecated, and unlikely to work on well-configured servers.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to do everything in one echo, and code indenting make it easier to read and debug.

```
<?php
    if (!$UserLoggedIn) {
        echo "PLEASE LOGIN";
    }else{ 
        echo "<div style='background: #FFF;padding: 25px;box-shadow: 0 2px #bbb;margin: auto;position:relative;width: 600px;'>
                <center>Welcome, {$GetLoggedUser->username}<br>
                    Here's some statistics about your account:<br>
                    Username: {$GetLoggedUser->username}<br>
                    Email: {$GetLoggedUser->email}<br>
                    UserID: {$GetLoggedUser->id}<br>
                    Banned from game: ";
        if($GetLoggedUser->banned == "0") { 
            echo " no "; 
        } else { 
            echo " yes  "; 
        }
        echo "<br>Banned from website: {$GetLoggedUser->Ban} (obviously not or this page   wouldn't show up)
        <center/><div/>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF), expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: Sorry. forgot a `:` after the seconnd echo. Fixed now

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to Echo everything...  Not how I would do this but example below you cannot do an If statement INSIDE an echo string, but you could do a ternary operation ie (value==true)?"Yes":"No" but easier to just break out of script and echo what you need too...

```
<?
if (!$UserLoggedIn) {

    echo "PLEASE LOGIN";
}else{ 
?>
<div style='background: #FFF;
padding: 25px;
box-shadow: 0 2px 2px #bbb;
margin: auto;
position:relative;
width: 600px;
'>
<center>
Welcome, <? echo $GetLoggedUser->username ?>
  <br>
Here's some statistics about your account:
  <br>
Username: <? echo  $GetLoggedUser->username ?>
  <br>
Email: <? echo $GetLoggedUser->email ?>
  <br>
UserID: <? echo $GetLoggedUser->id ?>
<br>
Banned from game: 
<? if($GetLoggedUser->banned == "0") { echo " no "; } else { echo " yes  ";     } ?>
  <br>
Banned from website: <? echo $GetLoggedUser->Ban ?> (obviously not or this page   wouldn't show up)
<center/>
<div/>
<? } ?>
```

Comment: Do not rely on [short open tags](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) working anywhere. They're old, deprecated, and unlikely to work on well-configured servers.

Answer (score 0):

To display bigger amounts of `HTML` I prefer to switch between `PHP` and `HTML` by closing and reopening the `PHP` tags.

I am using the short syntax of `echo` (`<?= ?>`) to insert values from `PHP` into `HTML`.

Some IDEs can not interpret `HTML` when it is encapsulated in `PHP`, so they can not help with `syntax highlighting` when you are just using echo to output your `HTML`.

```
<?php
if (!$UserLoggedIn) {
    echo "PLEASE LOGIN";
} else {
?>
    <div style='
         background: #FFF;
         padding: 25px;
         box-shadow: 0 2px 2px #bbb;
         margin: auto;
         position:relative;
         width: 600px;
         '>
        <center>
            Welcome, <?= $GetLoggedUser->username ?> 
            <br>
            Here's some statistics about your account:
            <br>
            Username: <?= $GetLoggedUser->username ?>
            <br>
            Email: <?= $GetLoggedUser->email ?>
            <br>
            UserID: <?= $GetLoggedUser->id ?>
            <br>
            Banned from game: <?= $GetLoggedUser->banned == '0' ? ' no ' : ' yes ' ?>
            <br>
            Banned from website: <?= $GetLoggedUser->Ban ?> (obviously not or this page   wouldn't show up)
        </center>
    </div>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can still try:
 Banned from game:

```
if($GetLoggedUser->banned     ==
"0") { echo " no "; } elseif           ($GetLoggedUser->banned       == "1") { echo "
yes "; }
```

Comment: WHAT? he is inside an echo string, this is pure nonsense!